# How do I blur login's background when the sign-up form is displayed?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two sections one for the login (#login) and the other for the registration form (# id01)
when I click on the add button to access it to the registration form I want the background (#login) to be blurry, how can i do this, need help please

**here is the html code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<!-- Required meta tags -->
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta
  name="viewport"
  content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
/>
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link
  rel="stylesheet"  href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="static\css\style1.css" />
<title>Login</title>
</head>

<body>
<section id="login">
  <div class="container login-container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 login-form-1">
        <h3>Utilisateur</h3>
        <form>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input
              type="text"
              class="form-control"
              placeholder="Votre mail *"
              value=""
            />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input
              type="password"
              class="form-control"
              placeholder="Votre mot de passe *"
              value=""
            />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" class="btnSubmit" value="Connexion" />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <a href="#" class="ForgetPwd">Mot de passe oublier ?</a>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 login-form-2">
        <div class="login-logo">
          <a
            onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'"
            style="width: auto"
            ><span
              ><img src="static/images/signUp.png" alt="Inscrire" /></span
          ></a>
        </div>
        <h3>Admin</h3>
        <form>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input
              type="text"
              class="form-control"
              placeholder="Votre mail *"
              value=""
            />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input
              type="password"
              class="form-control"
              placeholder="Votre mot de passe *"
              value=""
            />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" class="btnSubmit" value="Connexion" />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <a href="#" class="ForgetPwd" value="Login"
              >Mot de passe oublier ?</a
            >
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section id="signup">
  <div id="id01" class="modal">
    <span
      onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none',document.getElementById('login').style.opacity=1"
      class="close"
      title="Close Modal"
      >&times;</span
    >
    <div
      class="signup-form"
      style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; width: 500px"
    >
      <h3>S'inscrire</h3>
      <form>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            placeholder="Nom *"
            value=""
          />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            placeholder="Prenom *"
            value=""
          />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            placeholder="Email *"
            value=""
          />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input
            type="password"
            class="form-control"
            placeholder="Mot de passe *"
            value=""
          />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input
            type="password"
            class="form-control"
            placeholder="Confirmation Mot de passe *"
            value=""
          />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="submit" class="btnSubmit" value="Login" />
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
</body>

<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
></script>
<script    src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
></script>
<script
  src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
></script>
</body>
</html>
```

the js:

```
<script>
  // Get the modal
  var modal = document.getElementById("id01");

  window.onclick = function (event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
      modal.style.display = "none";
    }
  };
</script>
```

**the css code:**

```
.login-container {
margin-top: 5%;
margin-bottom: 5%}

.login-logo {
position: relative;
margin-left: -28.5%;}

.login-logo img {
position: absolute;
width: 25%;
margin-top: 19%;
background: #fff;
border-radius: 4.5rem;
padding: 5%;}
.login-form-1,.signup-form {
padding: 5%;
box-shadow: 0 5px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 9px 26px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
background-color: #fff;}

.login-form-1 h3,.signup-form h3 {
text-align: center;
color: #333;}

.login-form-2 {
padding: 5%;
background: #0062cc;
box-shadow: 0 5px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 9px 26px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);}

.login-form-2 h3 {
text-align: center;
color: #fff;}

.login-container form {
padding: 10%;}

.btnSubmit {
width: 50%;
border-radius: 1rem;
padding: 1.5%;
border: none;
cursor: pointer;}

.login-form-1 .btnSubmit,.signup-form .btnSubmit {
font-weight: 600;
color: #fff;
background-color: #0062cc;}

.login-form-2 .btnSubmit {
font-weight: 600;
color: #0062cc;
background-color: #fff;}

.login-form-2 .ForgetPwd {
color: #fff;
font-weight: 600;
text-decoration: none;}

.login-form-1 .ForgetPwd {
color: #0062cc;
font-weight: 600;
text-decoration: none;}

span {
cursor: pointer;}

.container {
padding: 16px;}

.modal {
display: none;
position: fixed;
z-index: 1;
left: 0;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
overflow: auto;
padding-top: 50px;}

hr {
border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
margin-bottom: 25px;}

.close {
position: absolute;
right: 35px;
font-size: 40px;
font-weight: bold;
color: #888;}

.close:hover,.close:focus {
color: #f44336;
cursor: pointer;}
```

waiting for a reply, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Add an event listener for `click` on the modal opener anchor that applys `filter: blur(5px)` to the login container.

Make sure to set the blur back to `0px` when you hide the modal.

Demo:

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("id01");
var c = document.querySelector('.login-container');
modalopener.addEventListener('click', function(){
  c.style.filter = "blur(5px)";
})
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    c.style.filter = "blur(0px)";
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
};
```

```css
.login-container {
  margin-top: 5%;
  margin-bottom: 5%
}

.login-logo {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: -28.5%;
}

.login-logo img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 25%;
  margin-top: 19%;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4.5rem;
  padding: 5%;
}

.login-form-1,
.signup-form {
  padding: 5%;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 9px 26px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  background-color: #fff;
}

.login-form-1 h3,
.signup-form h3 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #333;
}

.login-form-2 {
  padding: 5%;
  background: #0062cc;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 9px 26px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

.login-form-2 h3 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}

.login-container form {
  padding: 10%;
}

.btnSubmit {
  width: 50%;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  padding: 1.5%;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.login-form-1 .btnSubmit,
.signup-form .btnSubmit {
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #0062cc;
}

.login-form-2 .btnSubmit {
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #0062cc;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.login-form-2 .ForgetPwd {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.login-form-1 .ForgetPwd {
  color: #0062cc;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-decoration: none;
}

span {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.container {
  padding: 16px;
}

.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

hr {
  border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 35px;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #888;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #f44336;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="static\css\style1.css" />
  <title>Login</title>
</head>

<body>
  <section id="login">
    <div class="container login-container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 login-form-1">
          <h3>Utilisateur</h3>
          <form>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Votre mail *" value="" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Votre mot de passe *" value="" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="submit" class="btnSubmit" value="Connexion" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <a href="#" class="ForgetPwd">Mot de passe oublier ?</a>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 login-form-2">
          <div class="login-logo">
            <a onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block';" style="width: auto" id="modalopener"><span
              ><img src="static/images/signUp.png" alt="Inscrire" /></span
          ></a>
          </div>
          <h3>Admin</h3>
          <form>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Votre mail *" value="" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Votre mot de passe *" value="" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="submit" class="btnSubmit" value="Connexion" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <a href="#" class="ForgetPwd" value="Login">Mot de passe oublier ?</a
            >
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section id="signup">
  <div id="id01" class="modal">
    <span
      onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none',document.getElementById('login').style.opacity=1"
      class="close"
      title="Close Modal"
      >&times;</span
    >
    <div
      class="signup-form"
      style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; width: 500px"
    >
      <h3>S'inscrire</h3>
      <form>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            placeholder="Nom *"
            value=""
          />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            placeholder="Prenom *"
            value=""
          />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            placeholder="Email *"
            value=""
          />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input
            type="password"
            class="form-control"
            placeholder="Mot de passe *"
            value=""
          />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input
            type="password"
            class="form-control"
            placeholder="Confirmation Mot de passe *"
            value=""
          />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="submit" class="btnSubmit" value="Login" />
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
</body>

<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
></script>
<script    src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
></script>
<script
  src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
></script>
</body>
</html>
```